# Primefaces dataTable populate (search) doesn't work well after filtering

Tags: primefaces, datatable, primefaces-datatable

I have a Primefaces dataTable like this in a `<h:form>` block:

```
<p:dataTable id="basicDT" var="partyDB" value="#{mbRechercheAbonne.listPartyDB}" 
                             paginator="true" 
                             emptyMessage="Aucun abonné ne correspond aux critères"
                             paginatorPosition="bottom" 
                             paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" 
                             rows="25" 
                             paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                             rowsPerPageTemplate="25,50,100"
                             currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord} - {endRecord} sur {totalRecords} résultats"
                             filteredValue="#{mbRechercheAbonne.filteredListPartyDB}">
```

and a search button that populates the dataTable using a `@ViewScoped` bean that updates the value of `listPartyDB` when `rechercheAbonne()` is called:

```
<p:commandButton value="Rechercher" update="display :consultform:basicDT" icon="ui-icon-check"
                                     actionListener="#{mbRechercheAbonne.rechercheAbonne()}" onstart="startRecherche()" oncomplete="stopRecherche()"/>
```

Searching multiple times works, the dataTable's content changes like expected.

**However**, when using filtering and then removing the filter (i.e. adding a letter in a filter field above a column and then removing that letter), the search no longer works. I found that the search does actually work, but I need to apply a filter again (and remove it to have the unfiltered list) to see the result of the new search.

Explaining with pictures :

Searching for "test":
[image: Searching for "test"]

Searching for "abc" right after, works as intended:
[image: Searching for "abc"]

Searching for test again, filtering one column, works as intended:
[image: Filtering]

Removing the filter (going back to pic 1), and then searching for "abc". **Does not work:**
[image: Removing the filter]

Applying a filter again does it on the "abc" search that wasn't showing originally - removing the filter shows what the last search should have shown.
[image: Filtering again]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Always, always, always create a [mcve] (for yourself) first and try in the latest version and if that fails, create a question and always, always, always state version info, and before that, search the PF issuelist if not using the latest version.

Comment: The issue happens in the latest version and I didn't find it in the PF issuelist on Github. I'll do a MCVE but it's not like there is much code going on right now.

Comment: Might be my issue, looking into it : https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1753